# Pivot_table MultiIndex to columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, multi-index

I have the following table :

```
In [303]: table.head()
Out[303]: 
            people  weekday  weekofyear
2012-01-01     119        6          52
2012-01-02      76        0           1
2012-01-03      95        1           1
2012-01-04     102        2           1
2012-01-05      87        3           1
```

I would like to create a simple `pd.DataFrame` where :

- columns = [1, 2, ..., 52]  (weekofyear)
- rows = [0, 1, ..., 6]  (weekday)
- values = `np.sum`

I tried using `pd.pivot_table` which gave me the expected result :

```
In [308]: p = pd.pivot_table(table, index=["weekday"], columns=["weekofyear"], values=["people"], aggfunc=[np.sum])
     ...: p
     ...: 
Out[308]: 
              sum                                             ...             \
           people                                             ...              
weekofyear     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8   9    10 ...    43   44   
weekday                                                       ...              
0             162   86   84   95   92   98  108  102  97   87 ...   108   86   
1              95  113   88   78  108  112   98  104  87  105 ...    85   82   
2             102   70   93   82  103   80  103   85  82   96 ...    87  105   
3              87   91  101   83   91  100  100   80  89   86 ...    87   91   
4             111   91  110  103   93  116  110   99  78   77 ...    83  102   
5             117  107   99   88   97   90  100   91  97   88 ...   103  110   
6              92   95   90   86   91  103   98  100  89   96 ...    94  101   



weekofyear   45   46   47   48   49   50   51   52  
weekday                                             
0            99   92   99   83  107  106   93  107  
1           105   83  101   93  102   89  113   84  
2            96   84  110   83  104   84   84  116  
3            87   96   87   88   88   83  113   93  
4            93   81  104  108   72  101  109   97  
5            81  107   97   89   86  108  113  101  
6            93   92   93   91   89   96   93  226  

[7 rows x 52 columns]
```

**but** instead of having my *weekofyears* columns, I got stuck with a MultiIndex I could not get rid of. As shown below :

```
In [309]: p.columns
Out[309]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[['sum'], ['people'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51]],
           names=[None, None, 'weekofyear']
```

while the index seems fine :

```
In [311]: p.index
Out[311]: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype='int64', name='weekday'
```

I tried playing with `unstack()` & `reset_index()` functions, without success.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of giving lists to `values` and `aggfunc`, you should try giving single values to them. Example -

```
p = pd.pivot_table(table, index=["weekday"], columns=["weekofyear"], values="people", aggfunc=np.sum)
```

---

Demo -

```
In [3]: table
Out[3]:
            people  weekday  weekofyear
2012-01-01     119        6          52
2012-01-02      76        0           1
2012-01-03      95        1           1
2012-01-04     102        2           1
2012-01-05      87        3           1

In [12]: p = pd.pivot_table(table, index=["weekday"], columns=["weekofyear"], values="people", aggfunc=np.sum)

In [13]: p
Out[13]:
weekofyear   1    52
weekday
0            76  NaN
1            95  NaN
2           102  NaN
3            87  NaN
6           NaN  119

In [14]: p.columns
Out[14]: Int64Index([1, 52], dtype='int64', name='weekofyear')
```

---

From [documentation -](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html)

> *aggfunc : function, default numpy.mean, or list of functions*
>   If list of functions passed, the resulting pivot table will have hierarchical columns whose top level are the function names (inferred from the function objects themselves)

Similar is the case with `values` , though not specifically mentioned in the documentation